# SVG - Pattern with image background - images do not fill the same - adapt to the shape they are contained in

Tags: html, css, svg, charts, mapping

I am trying to get areas of states to fill up based off certain criteria. I have a pattern and it is working, but it seems like the pattern fills up the territory based off the shape of the territory. I want to have the lines the same when they fill every single shape. You can see in the map below that the lines are not at the same degree nor are they the same size in each state. Is this possible? I am new to SVG.

[image]

Patterns:

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="pattern-stripe" width="5" height="4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(75)">
        <rect width="2" height="4" transform="translate(0,0)" fill="white"></rect>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="mask-stripe">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-stripe)" />
    </mask>   
    <pattern id="other" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <image height="10" width="10" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="images/other-stripe.png" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="blue" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <image height="10" width="10" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="images/blue-stripe.png" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="orange" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <image height="10" width="10" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="images/orange-stripe.png" />
    </pattern>


</defs>
```

Comment: I can't help buy think `preserveAspectRatio="none` might be relevant here.

Comment: if i remove it, the shape has no fill... it just goes to white.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the error in CodePen, but without the complete SVG code, it didn't work. However, I think if you replace `preserveAspectRatio="none"` with `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` it will fix your problem. If it doesn't, but it makes progress, try the other solutions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio).

Answer (score 0):

You want `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"`. Meet will change your aspect ratio until the minimum of height or width fits the bounding box. Slice will crop the fill to the available space.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your patterns are using `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"`.
This means that the stripey image in your patterns is being scaled to match the size of the shape the pattern is applied to.

**Demo:**

```html
<svg>

  <defs>
    <pattern id="blue" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
       <image height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>


  <rect x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150" fill="url(#blue)"/>
  <rect x="175" y="25" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#blue)"/>
</svg>
```

To fix this, you need to use `patternContentUnits` that are independent of the size of the shape the pattern is applied to.  You do this by specifying `patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`.

```html
<svg>

  <defs>
    <pattern id="blue" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <image height="150" width="150" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>


  <rect x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150" fill="url(#blue)"/>
  <rect x="175" y="25" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#blue)"/>
</svg>
```